# Understanding Number of units in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

The graph is of RequestCountPerTarget for an ecs service. My intent is to understand and in this case how much request is handled by this target (ecs task) within some AZ.
As per the graph, on the left hand side(highlighted), it says 0, 0.5, 1 and I have selected statistics as 'Average' for a 1 minute.

[image]

What does 0, 0.5, 1 in Y -axis indicates? Is this in percentage or 0.5 means 500 request or something else?
If I select statistics as 'Sum', then I can see the request in hundreds/thousands etc.
My intent is to see average no of request in 1 min/sec etc?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got my answer up to larger extent. As per the [docs][1], under "RequestCountPerTarget" section, it says:
**Statistics**: *The only valid statistic is Sum. This represents the average not the sum.*

So, whatever you see, its always average. In my case, I have intentionally set min/max task count as 1 and so all those number will be applicable to that one task only as an average count.

Also, with this docs, I would assume, the 0, 0.5. 1 and so is just a data point to show on the graph. Hope my theory is correct?

If possible, others experienced folks can confirm the above docs & theory just to be on the same page.
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#target-metric-table